# Stuck with type inferences with generic classes

Tags: typescript, class, generics

I am trying since weeks but still can't get my head around what is going on. I'm trying to infer types inside the function arguments and a callback return type.

This is how far I got. I have managed to **infer the return type** of `cb` but do not have access to `T["id"]` in the `cb` params.

```js
type MyObj<T extends string> = {
  id: T;
  cb: (p?: { [K in T]: any }) => any;
} 

class MyClass<const T extends MyObj<string>> {
  constructor(p: T[]) {}

  get <K extends T["id"]>(p: K): ReturnType<Extract<T, { id: K }>["cb"]> { 
    return null as any;
  }
}

const my = new MyClass([
  {
    id: "foo",
    cb: (p) => "foo"
  },
  {
    id: "bar",
    cb: (p) => 1
  }
]);

const r1 = my.get("foo"); // string
const r2 = my.get("bar"); // number
```

However, I would like to have the string literals for `T["id"]` available for the parameter in `cb` when calling the class constructor. I got to this:

```js
const MyClass<const T extends string> {
  constructor(p: MyObj<T>) {}

  get <K extends MyObj<T>["id"]>(p: K): ReturnType<Extract<MyObject<K>, {id: K}>["cb"]>
}

const my2 = new MyClass([
  {
    id: "foo",
    cb: (p) => {
      // p is { ["foo" | "bar"]: any }
      return "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    id: "bar",
    cb: (p) => 1
  }
]);

const r3 = my2.get("foo"); // any
const r4 = my2.get("bar"); // any
```

Now I have access to the string literals for the parameter but cannot infer the return type of `cb`. Is it possible to have both somehow?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVgHgCpQgD2BAdgCYDOUxwATgJb4DmAfFALxQDeAsAFBRRWEBcUdAG4uPAMaJBACjAB+QaygBtANK98QgLqCAhvhBQAvgEpmjfSFGcjULvc7iANruKk4AYRdvU4gPb45EJYuAQksAgoqOTUdPSMHNxQ-oGUAK7iwH4UsoLoylpmrEYOPLQQwFCo6jh4RKT5AER8jVr0uVCqJoIAShVpFPjo4BCoAKK4FLqZGAA0bLwCncb0yo2SrQl2STwU-YNQ+GlOTlCuZwbWPCU2DilBALaGLPgQAO4RXq7E0spibP8eHxBI0AGZ+PyNWaA5JSKCyMxMRhgiGNf5GaFJRI8IFLRqIXQUKEwyQyMCIxgARnRXEK1i490qFEpzCgTwAdOVgNIUZCTNYAPQCsiUGi0O4BIIUABMrI5XJ5BKJ-K4QsOaQeiAgFAcDO87hAXzc0t8ksqmFqYVIMTFCVKyTNFAyWRyYEEcCQaHQq0KbBu-y5VRqoXqEU9GFWzUImw6XV6+yGI3Gk2mwFQHqiqno81YwM6RkjGzafq4-scZrZIFlL3en310t+-2xOLzvOJO1hZIpAI7PDVYF4pCUa3BkKgAB8oPjCa09AZjDDdgmp6O0R2btdMTxm7iQUr2zjO-DyeYoNSkjc6RLUlAKABmOVVzkVHmrlWcNWWa9SgAsj+lz7ctOyqCsKlhAA)

Here is a [minimal reproducible example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.2.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDyAjAVgHgCpQgD2BAdgCYDOUxwATgJb4DmAfFALxQDeAsAFBRRWEBcUdAG4uPAMaJBACjAB%20QaygBtANK98QgLqCAhvhBQAvgEpmjfSFGcjULvc7iANruKk4AYRdvU4gPb45EJYuAQksAgoqOTUdPSMHJxiUMCC6MpayRQQxApsytiCMTS0OlCWRg4SATEAruLAfhSyaRlmiTw8wAAWVMQAdMDMUGDJlUncULQQQ6jqOHhEpOkARHwrWvQtUKomggBKM7UU%20OjgEKgAorgUug0YADRsvAI7xvTKK5IbCXaT1YEhuJhj0%20oN%20gAzKhOPDNIZMRjAfp8ZhMFhgExVTr%20QFQSSHUgscTKAAMWn6kmkoIG2WIJmsnRSvRpOSgcigVOZ-VpyjAWmG%20JyZhk1O5rJYSl5ZUFpFM1mSPGywGOmhlDOMXHGXCcMygAFtDCx8BAAO4RLyuYjSZTJDqdPiCFYQvx%20FYPBV4qQcjHmKBOl0rMbuyZ2ngOv2IXQUN0eyQyH0ItgengAehTUAAkgByQhQJxUADW0EaUG6ugAbtA7uIcqQS7onE4hJ91lpSM6KCNk1AlSqoABGKAAahGckhLv6OroPQ94x44y09IcOKCFEHLAN-WmwGk-tdS%204K78Osnflou8ASYRQZ2up5rg9cFdDCgAJmGm%203u8j0YPR5PTjPS8oG-N0exfekgA) to better explain what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I doubt you fix this with typings; simultaneous contextual typing and generic type inference is hard for TypeScript. There's an open suggestion at [ms/TS#47599](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47599), and there's occasional progress in some situations, but there will always be cases where the compiler sees a circular dependency and gives up, and this looks like one of those cases.  Why are you using `p` in your callbacks if the return type doesn't depend on it? What purpose does `p` serve? A [mre] which actually uses `p` might help us suggest alternatives.

Comment: Hey @jcalz! Thanks for the answer!  Yes, I went through [ms/TS#47599](https://t.ly/nMTpc) but unfortunately I'm having a hard time to understand what is going on there.  Anyway, I have skipped the return type dependency for `p` for now since  I think it causes way less problems. Ideally the return type of `p` would be the return type of `cb` where `p[key === id]`. So, in the above example `typeof p.foo = string` and `typeof p.bar = number`. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Regarding a minimal example, hope [this](https://t.ly/eHFwx) is what you meant.

Comment: Please [edit] to put the [mre] code in the question text. I'm not sure what's confusing about ms/TS#47599; since `p` depends on `T` and `T` depends on `p` then that's circular; if TS could infer `T` in stages, it might work, but it can't in this case.  Given your updated example, I'd say the best way to proceed is to break the circularity by actually building the object in stages where each stage only depends on the previous ones. Possibly like [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wgBevW). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks again! I have added the example to the question text. What is confusing? Well, I guess it is just me having a hard time to see similarities between my problem and what is listed in TS#47599. I guess I'm generally still struggling with TS. However, thank you so much for your approach! It is very interesting but please give me a couple of days to properly go through it and play around with it! I'll let you know when I'm done so you can maybe formulate an answer and earn those precious StackOverflow points. Thank you so much!!!!